# how to retrieve sent messages from openfire server using smack4.1 for android chat app?

Tags: android, openfire

I am using openfire server and smack4.1 api for android chat app.
I sent messages to roster items through ChatManager class. Now i want to show sent messages.  I used the below code to get messages. But i am unable to get sent messages from server.
Could any one help me, how to retrieve messages using smack4.1 api?

I am using below code:

```
OfflineMessageManager msgMgr = new OfflineMessageManager(mConnection);
List<Message> it = msgMgr.getMessages();  
System.out.println(": " + it.size());
System.out.println(": " + msgMgr.getMessageCount());
```

It always gives zero count, event receiver having records in 'ofoffline'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: means you do not do anything ?

Comment: Give more information about any error messages / behaviors that are relevant to your question. It's always helpful to include a code snippet too.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you mean with "I am unable to get sent messages from server.". You should elaborate and rephrase it.